# Searching Linked lists of an Array and removing a link

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, linked-list

I have an array of linked lists, and use two for loops to search through each linked list on the array. Anyone any tips on how I remove the item when I have found it?

```
public UserApp(int max){
 a= new User[max];
 nElems=0;
}

int maxSize=100;
UserApp arr;
arr= new UserApp(maxSize);

arr.insert("Evans", "Patty", 24);         // insert 10 items
arr.insert("Smith", "Doc", 59);
arr.insert("Smith", "Lorraine", 37);
arr.insert("Smith", "Paul", 37);
arr.insert("Yee", "Tom", 43);
arr.insert("Hash", "Doc", 21);
arr.insert("Stimson", "John", 29);
arr.insert("Evans", "Jose", 72);
arr.insert("Yang", "Doc", 22);
arr.insert("Creswell", "Lucinda", 18);

LinkedList[] myList = new LinkedList[3];
myList[0] = new LinkedList();
myList[0].add(a[1]);
myList[0].add(a[2]);
myList[0].add(a[3]);

myList[1] = new LinkedList();
myList[1].add(a[4]);
myList[1].add(a[3]);

myList[2] = new LinkedList();
myList[2].add(a[2]);
myList[2].add(a[9]);

public void deleteFromList(User found){

  for (int i=0; i<myList.length; i++){
     for (int j=0; j<myList[i].size(); j++){
        if (myList[i].listIterator(j).next().equals(found));
       // then delete
```

Comment: Can you please provide your insert and your search function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over the Array is already done right.

To iterate over the elements of the linked list you should use [iterator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#iterator--) an uses its [remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) method to remove elements from the list while iterating over it.